# TcpListener.AcceptSocketAsync issues in Windows 7

Tags: c#, network-programming, windows-7-x64

I have old .NET code which uses TcpListener and needs to run on Windows 7 and Windows 10 PCs.
Initially it uses a separate thread where a blocking call to TcpListener.AcceptSocket is used. On application exit Thread.Abort() is called to kill that thread. All incoming connections work ok on both Win 7 and Win 10, but Abort causes some issues. It is a rough way to exit, not recommended anyway.

I change it to use Tasks + TcpListener.AcceptSocketAsync. It is more elegant solution + fixes exit issues caused by Thread.Abort(). Works perfectly on Win 10 but on Win 7 client connections don't pass. Note, it is the same Win 7 PC where the synchronous method works. I can test it in minutes by rolling code back and forth.

Here is an extract of async network code:

```
            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port)
            {
                ExclusiveAddressUse = false
            };
            listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
            listener.Start();
            while(!stop)
            {
                Socket  sck;
                
                try
                {
                    sck = await listener.AcceptSocketAsync();
                }
                catch...
// process exceptions, exit conditions, read data
            }
```

Does anyone know about specific issues of TcpListener.AcceptSocketAsync on Win 7?

.NET framework 4.7.2 and Windows 7 x64 are used.

Thanks!

Comment: "*Works perfectly on Win 10 but on Win 7 client connections don't pass*" - this doesn't sound right. You need to add code

Comment: @MichaelRandall: Indeed, you are right. Added.